# Change background color of ListBoxItem when it is not focused

Tags: c#, wpf, wpf-controls

I try to change the Backgroundcolor of the selected ListBoxItem when it is not focused and the containing window is not active. The Window has `ShowActivated = false.`  But it is still grey.

Here is my code:

```
        <ListBox x:Name="oList" >
        <ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
            <Style TargetType="{x:Type ListBoxItem}">
                <EventSetter Event="MouseDoubleClick"
                             Handler="listBoxItem_DoubleClick" />
                <Style.Resources>
                    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.HighlightBrushKey}"
                                     Color="LightGreen" />
                    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.ControlBrushKey}"
                                     Color="LightBlue" />
                </Style.Resources>
            </Style>
        </ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>

        <ListBoxItem Content="Coffie"></ListBoxItem>
        <ListBoxItem Content="Tea"></ListBoxItem>
        <ListBoxItem Content="Orange Juice"></ListBoxItem>
        <ListBoxItem Content="Milk"></ListBoxItem>
        <ListBoxItem Content="Iced Tea"></ListBoxItem>
        <ListBoxItem Content="Mango Shake"></ListBoxItem>
    </ListBox>
```

I hope someone can help me, what I am doing wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding this in your `Style.Resources` (change color to your liking):

```
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.InactiveSelectionHighlightBrushKey}" Color="LightBlue"/>
```

Comment: This does work but has to be set in the style you set for your listbox items container. (Where you put your other color overrides).

Comment: When I use SystemColors.InactiveSelectionHighlightBrushKey there will be an exception.